# How do I generate ri documentation for custom objects and methods?

Tags: ruby, ri

I have some custom RDoc data generated for my app.  I want to create custom RI documentation as well, but I can't find the command for this anywhere.  What is it?

```
ri Hash
```

returns a man page.

```
ri CustomObject
```

does not.  I want both to return man pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `rdoc` from the directory containing your code, it can generate both ri and rdoc documents.

See the output of `rdoc --help`, or read through the [RDoc site](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html) to learn more about the options, but in general you want the `--ri-site` flag.

Comment: --ri-site was the flag I needed.  Thanks